# NServiceBus command handler fired again and again

Tags: nservicebus

i am having a handler for a NserviceBus command, in its handler, we have a process which is reading an xml, but that is taking time. So now what happens is that the time when the xml is being read, the command handler fires up again and it fires number of times which I have configured as max retries, 5 in this case.

This is some code :-

```
class SendHandler :
    IHandleMessages<SendCommand>
{ 
public SendHandler()
    {
        ------some code
    }


    public void Handle(SendCommand message)
    {   *1   
          -----there is some code which is taking time
          -----the line number (*1) is fired again and again by the time processing takes place
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure another message isn't being sent and handled?

Comment: How much time is it taking to process the message, and what transport are you using?

Comment: @phil there is another message being sent from this handler and that's being handled some where else.

Comment: @chad it is taking around 20-30 secs. And I am using msmq

Comment: Or, is there any way to change the configuration of the bus for a particular command. like the config set in app.config is '<TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel="4" MaxRetries="5" />'..i want to override this app.config for a particular case only through code. Any help...!!

Comment: @King really your choice here is to look at how you are handling the xml file or increase your transaction timeout, like Sean said. I would personally examine how you can make the xml processing more efficient/faster. Either that or do the work outside of the scope of a message handler.

Comment: isnt there any way by which we can configure the nservicebus at the message level, i mean use the CustomConfigurationSource for a particular message to have some value and app.config values for the otehr messages.

Answer (score 2):

Check your First and Second level retry settings ([FLR/SLR](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/automatic-retries)
As suggested in comments, try on a single command message in your queue. 
If handler is not done with XML processing, check if it exceeds the default [transaction timeout](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/transactions-message-processing#specifying-transactions-in-code). If so, review the approach you're taking with handler since you might need a long(er) running process.

Comment: If he is using azure transport, he might be running into the peeklock timeout too, which defaults to something like 30s.  Particular would do well to offer some guidance on how to handle longer running processes that can't be processed within a transaction timeout as well. Unless the docs have been updated, I know it would have helped us get started.

Comment: @ChadRuppert good point. LockDuration time can be extended up to 5 minutes. Beyond that, one should really look into changing code approach. If it is a long running process, then Sagas could be used. If it's not a long running process, but does require long processing time, a separate thread.

Comment: Or, is there any way to change the configuration of the bus for a particular command. like the config set in app.config is '<TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel="4" MaxRetries="5" />'..i want to override this app.config for a particular case only through code. Any help...!!

Comment: @King if your command type requires different FLR/SLR configuration, I'd suggest to look into splitting that command to be handled by a separate endpoint where those settings would be applied.

Comment: isnt there any way by which we can configure the nservicebus at the message level, i mean use the CustomConfigurationSource for a particular message to have some value and app.config values for the otehr messages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't specify FLR/SLR settings at a message level. They can only be specified at an endpoint level. If an endpoint is handling different messages, it is better to group them based on the message SLA. So, separate the message types with differing SLA to a different endpoint. Can you please post what your use case is in the Google groups here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware and we can chime in? Thanks.